# Azure AD Conditional Access testing disabled policy

Tags: azure, entra-id

I'm trying to set up Azure AD conditional access. While doing this, I of course want to test the policy I've created. So, I open the what-if tool, put in appropriate information, and click the button. But the policy doesn't apply because it's disabled.

Why does the policy being disabled prevent me from testing it?! It's disabled *because* I'm testing it and don't want to break everything! Do I have to create a whole test account, reassign the policy to it, and enable it just to see if the policy works? It seems like if there's a testing tool it should be able to check if a policy will work right before I enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to test the policy on an actual user and you must have a user.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/what-if-tool
[image]

Comment: That's rather irritating. Guess I've got some feedback to submit. Thanks.